# How to get variable outside form into php

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

How to get a variable that is not inside a `<form>` tag

```
var vvv = document.getElementById('vvv');
```

into php

```
$variable=vvv.value;
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the question for better understanding? Are you trying to send a JS value to PHP ?

Comment: Create a hidden element and assign the javascript value to it using the element's ID

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you talk about javascript to php variable. To understand how this works you will probably need to use AJAX. This is a good start:
[JQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Once you get a hold of that you can send your javascript-variable to a PHP-webservice and have fun with it.